# Click outside menu to close it with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to close a menu by clicking outside it (including the link to open the menu) without using event.stopPropagation().

jQuery

```
$('a').click(function() {
  if ($(this).next().is(':visible')) $(this).next().hide();
  else $(this).next().show();
});
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('a, ul'))  return false;
  else $('ul').hide();
});
```

CSS

```
td { padding:20px; }
ul { display:none; position:absolute; background:yellow; padding:10px; }
```

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="#">show</a><ul>list 1</ul></td>
<td><a href="#">show</a><ul>list 2</ul></td>
<td><a href="#">show</a><ul>list 3</ul></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d8o6L71g/

The only problem with this code is that other menus remain open when I click to open another menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specifically tell when you want the menu to disappear. How about you hide all before showing? http://jsfiddle.net/d8o6L71g/3/

```js
  $('a').click(function() {
    if ($(this).next().is(':visible'))
    {
     $(this).next().hide();
    }
    else
    {
      $('a').next().hide();
      $(this).next().show();
    }
    
  });
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('a, ul'))
    {
      return false;
    }
    else 
    {
      $('ul').hide();
    }
  });
```

```css
td { padding:20px; }
ul { display:none; position:absolute; background:yellow; padding:10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="#">show</a><ul>list 1</ul></td>
<td><a href="#">show</a><ul>list 2</ul></td>
<td><a href="#">show</a><ul>list 3</ul></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Josh. It works fine, but I forgot to mention I have links inside the menus and when I click them I don't want the menus to close either. Any solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sure @tahoma you could use ID's to target which you want opened and closed. If you can update your html to reflect what you have, I can help provide a solution. thanks!

Comment: Here's an example of a table I will have on the page, with dropdown menus under the links in the right columns (only cell 6, 7, 9 in first row here). Due to the large number of links and menus, IDs wouldn't be practical I think. Is it not possible to somehow use td > div in the script so that links inside the open menu doesn't cause it to close when clicked? http://jsfiddle.net/d8o6L71g/17/

Comment: I figured it out, by changing the first selector from "a" to "td > a". Thanks again.

Comment: awesome news @tahoma ! best of luck in your coding.